# Role of neuraminidase in preventing polyspermy in humans

Tags: human-biology, reproduction, human-physiology, sexual-reproduction

Neuraminidase is a hydrolytic enzyme present in the acrosome of human sperm. It removes neuraminic acid (salic acid) from glycoproteins. I have read in a book that due to this reason it (the enzyme) prevents polyspermy. Can anyone corroborate both of these statements?